# Piece of jQuery code to enable class selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not using jQuery, but I have one line of code that enables the `$` selector shortcut, as follows:

```
let $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
```

I would like to also add whatever code necessary so that I can use the class selector shortcut as well.
Right now I have this:

```
let $c = function (cl) { return document.getElementsByClassName(cl); }
```

And I can select elements by class with `$c("some-class")`, but that returns a list that I need to then cycle through.

I would like to be able to use stuff like `$(".some-class").remove("some-class")` - to remove the class from all elements that have it without having to have a loop cycle through the list and remove them one by one.

Could anyone point me toward the part of jQuery that does that so I can include it and not the entire library?

I tried looking through the jQuery code for the term `className` but there are 39 instances and I'm not sure which part I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing native JS has to jQuery's sizzle selector engine is `querySelector()` or `querySelectorAll()`, depending on whether you're expecting a single element to be found, or multiple.

In your example, this would be:

```
let $ = selector => document.querySelectorAll(selector);
```

Comment: Thank you!  But what if you don't know if it will be a single or multiple elements found?

Comment: Then you would need to assume everything is a collection and work with it as such. Alternatively, wrap this in some logic which makes that determination for you at the point you attempt to interact with the resulting objects. However at that point you've effectively re-written jQuery so the entire point of this exercise becomes moot and will have wasted your time so you may as well have just used jQuery from the start.

Comment: Well couldn't I just pull the part of the jquery code that does this?  I assume I could keep all the code in it that references classname and scrap the rest.  But that still seems like more code than I need and I couldn't quite tell which parts were specific to this.

Comment: You could try, but it would be like just pulling the paint out of a cup of water. The two are mixed and rely on each other. Any attempt to separate them is almost futile. As I mentioned above, jQuery uses the [Sizzle selector engine](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki), which you can incorporate in to your own code, but this is not a trivial task.

Comment: Oh, well thanks!  I had no idea that sizzle was its own thing!  Well great, I'll just use that instead.